# Redirect wp-login

Tags: login, wp-redirect, wp-login-form

I have a custom page called owner-login that has a `wp_login_form()`

How can I disable wp-login.php so that:

- when a user writes `wp-admin/` it will redirect him to the owner-login (if not logged)
- when a user writes `wp-login.php` it will redirect him to the owner-login (logged/not logged)

Generally, I don't want to show wp-login, but to have the functionality for the scripts that require

Comment: keep in mind that out of the box WordPress adds pretty permalinks for example.com/admin /dashboard /logout and /login

Comment: What is the difference between what you want and how things already work?

Comment: My custom page is a template page with `wp_login_form()`, but on failure or by typing wp-admin/ (!logged in) it shows the plain vanilla wp-login.php page, which I don't want it to be shown. I want it to be redirected to my template page but keep the functionality of wp-login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

```
function is_login() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}
function redirect_login() {
    if ( is_login() ) {
        wp_redirect('http://example.com/customloginpage');
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_login' );
```

You'll need to modify the URL it redirects to, and test thoroughly.